# Grouping customers under a parent account in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, plugin, shipping-address, billing-address, b2b

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to create a parent account(B2B Unit) and be able to create customer's accounts associated with the parent. It is required that the customers use the parent's billing and shipping address during the checkout process. Any recommendations for either how to implement it or which plugin to use? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You will see that this is built into Magento 2 after Magento 2.2

> The individuals who are associated with a company are represented in
>   the Customers grid by the customer type, “Company User,” and are
>   typically buyers with varying levels of permission to access store
>   services and resources.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/b2b/user_guide/customers/account-company-users.html